# Mysql issue,query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm having some trouble with mysql,so i posted with ajax the parameter "user" i got the sql connected for sure,but somewhy it doesnt do what i want it to do.Here's my code:

```
    $ffs="select * from mex_szerzo where sznev=".$_POST["user"];
    $vissza=mysql_query($ffs);
    $sor=mysql_fetch_array($vissza);
    $user=$sor["sznev"];
    print ($user);
```

the $user is empy somewhy,the $_POST["user"] got value for sure,if i print it,it prints the actual user,i keep the users in a database,the username is stored as "sznev" for sure too,still the $user comes bk as an empy variable.

Comment: Use [MysqlPDO](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to avoid sql injection

Comment: Please read up on sql injection, deprecated methods, and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the quotes around your string value:

```
$ffs="select * from mex_szerzo where sznev=".$_POST["user"];
```

should be:

```
$ffs="select * from mex_szerzo where sznev='".$_POST["user"]."'";
```

You have no error checking in your code. That's why you didn't know what was wrong. Look into using `mysql_error()`.

Or, better yet, stop using an obsolete API altogether. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Look into using `mysqli` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

your query should be:

```
  $ffs="select * from mex_szerzo where sznev='".$_POST["user"]."'";
```

Comment: I think your quotes are off. Also, why the space at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the string and make sure your quote types encapsulate the query properly (single vs double quotes).

`$ffs="select * from mex_szerzo where sznev='".$_POST['user']."'";`